# How to know if belongTo data is saved in octobercms

Tags: php, octobercms

I have hasMany, belongTo relationship in octobercms, when i click on a category attached to a product, it saves but on refresh it goes back to the first option in the select box.It doesn't seem to saved with the product. I'm i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

```
{!! Form::select('category_id', $categoryLists, $categoryId, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

You need pass third parameter to set category selected. Here $categoryLists is list of all categories and $categoryId is saved category in product table.